# Checking residual of GeoTIFF if it came from db

Tags: raster, qgis-3, georeferencing, residuals

Let's say we have a GeoTIFF georeferenced by points indicated manually on map canvas. Is it possible to check residual accuracy of the raster if the layer comes without points file (in GeoPackage for example) I wonder?

Comment: Do you mean that you have warped the image and saved it into GeoPackage? Have you saved also the ground control points somehow into GeoPackage?

Comment: Yes, raster map was saved into GeoPackage, but not GCP points. At least I did not do it on purpouse. I can open this project from GeoPackage on another computer having my raster on the right place.

Comment: In that case all that you have is an image that does not know anything about the ground control points that has been utilized in georeferencing. The GCPs have disappeared in the process.

Comment: OK. I feel that I'm going beyond the topic of the question I've asked, but does it mean that without GCP points we can check the accuracy of georeferencing only visually?

Comment: Yes. Once you have materialized the result of warping you have only pixels that can be used for evaluating the accuracy. Notice also that the residuals are not absolute but they depend on the resampling method. If you use the thin plate spline method the residuals are always zero, and 1st, 2nd, and 3dr order polynomial functions all give different residuals with the same ground control points.  For quality control it would be optimal to have ground control points which are not used for georeferencing but it may be hard to get such.